# How can I make my title-case regular expression match prefix titles?

Tags: python, regex

I need to pull possible titles out of a chunk of text.  So for instance, I want to match words like "Joe Smith", "The Firm", or "United States of America".  I now need to modify it to match names that begin with a title of some kind (such as "Dr. Joe Smith").  Here's the regular expression I have:

```
NON_CAPPED_WORDS = (
    # Articles
    'the',
    'a',
    'an',

    # Prepositions
    'about',
    'after',
    'as',
    'at',
    'before',
    'by',
    'for',
    'from',
    'in',
    'into',
    'like',
    'of',
    'on',
    'to',
    'upon',
    'with',
    'without',
    )

TITLES = (
    'Dr\.',
    'Mr\.',
    'Mrs\.',
    'Ms\.',
    'Gov\.',
    'Sen\.',
    'Rep\.',
    )

# These are words that don't match the normal title case regex, but are still allowed
# in matches
IRREGULAR_WORDS = NON_CAPPED_WORDS + TITLES

non_capped_words_re = r'[\s:,]+|'.join(IRREGULAR_WORDS)
TITLE_RE = re.compile(r"""(?P<title>([A-Z0-9&][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\s,:-]*|{0})+\s*)""".format(non_capped_words_re))
```

Which builds the following regular expression:

```
(?P<title>([A-Z0-9&][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\s,:-]*|the[\s:,]+|a[\s:,]+|an[\s:,]+|about[\s:,]+|after[\s:,]+|as[\s:,]+|at[\s:,]+|before[\s:,]+|by[\s:,]+|for[\s:,]+|from[\s:,]+|in[\s:,]+|into[\s:,]+|like[\s:,]+|of[\s:,]+|on[\s:,]+|to[\s:,]+|upon[\s:,]+|with[\s:,]+|without[\s:,]+|Dr\.[\s:,]+|Mr\.[\s:,]+|Mrs\.[\s:,]+|Ms\.[\s:,]+|Gov\.[\s:,]+|Sen\.[\s:,]+|Rep\.)+\s*)
```

This doesn't seem to be working though:

```
>>> whitelisting.TITLE_RE.findall('Dr. Joe Smith')
[('Dr', 'Dr'), ('Joe Smith', 'Smith')]
```

Can someone who has better regex-fu help me fix this mess of a regex?

Comment: Just FYI, the backslashes aren't escaping the periods in your `TITLES`, since the strings are not raw literals

Comment: @zerocrates is right, but @Cameron is correct to point out that I should probably be a bit more explicit about it.  :-)

Comment: The prefix titles already basically comply with your title case regex, except for the punctuation. Do you have an aversion to allowing periods in your "normal" expression and skipping the special handling of the prefixes? Or have I missed some important subtlety in the expression?

Comment: @zerocrates: I learn something new every day. Thanks for calling me out on that :-)

Comment: Might also look at titles of 'Rev\.' and 'Hon\.'

Comment: Can I suggest you step back and look at NLTK instead. It has tooling for this kind of stuff: http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch05.html .. (I think there's a line where you should stop flogging regex, and I think you just sprinted way past it). ;) Seriously though, NLTK rocks

Comment: @zerocrates - Consider the following:  "I program in Python.  Joe Smith does too."  how would I stop it from matching "Python.  Joe Smith"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the first part of the expression, `[A-Z0-9&][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\s,:-]*`, is gobbling up the initial characters in your "prefix titles", since they are title-cased until you get to the period. So, when the `+` is repeating the subexpression and encounters `'Dr.'`, that initial part of the expression matches `'Dr'`, and leaves only the non-matching period.

One easy fix is to simply move the "special cases" to the front of the expression, so they're matched as a first resort, not a last resort (this essentially just moves `{0}` from the end of the expression to the front):

```
TITLE_RE = re.compile(r"""(?P<title>({0}|[A-Z0-9&][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\s,:-]*)+\s*)""".format(non_capped_words_re))
```

Result:

```
>>> TITLE_RE.findall('Dr. Joe Smith');
[('Dr. Joe Smith', 'Smith')]
```

I would probably go further and modify the expression to avoid all the repetition of `[\s:,]+`, but I'm not sure there's any real benefit, aside from making the formatted expression look a little nicer:

```
'|'.join(IRREGULAR_WORDS)
TITLE_RE = re.compile(r"""(?P<title>((?:{0})[\s:,]+|[A-Z0-9&][a-zA-Z0-9]*[\s,:-]*)+\s*)""".format(non_capped_words_re))
```